# Snippet to get prime numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get prime numbers with the following script

I am getting errors while executing it

```
class PrimeClass(Object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.givenNumber= number 
        self.outputPrimeNumbers=[]

    def getPrimeNumbers(self): 
        primes =[] 
        for possiblePrime in range(2,self.givenNumber + 1): 
            isPrime =True
        for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
            if possiblePrime % num == 0: 
                isPrime =False
            if isPrime: 
                primes.append(possiblePrime)
        self.outputPrimeNumbers=primes
        return(primes)

@property
def getOutputPrimeNumbers(self):
    return self.getOutputPrimeNumbers

primeClass=PrimeClass(123)
print(primeClass.getOutputPrimeNumbers)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Typo? `print(primeClass.getOutputPrimeNumbers())`

Answer (score 0):

Python is very strict about indentation. And the way your example is formatted it won't ever work.

But with my Python 2.7, the following worked:

```
class PrimeClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.givenNumber= number
        self.outputPrimeNumbers=[]

    def getPrimeNumbers(self):
        primes =[]
        for possiblePrime in range(2,self.givenNumber + 1):
            isPrime =True
            for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
                if possiblePrime % num == 0:
                    isPrime =False
            if isPrime:
                primes.append(possiblePrime)
        self.outputPrimeNumbers=primes
        return(primes)

    @property
    def getOutputPrimeNumbers(self):
        return self.getOutputPrimeNumbers

primeClass=PrimeClass(123)
print(primeClass.getPrimeNumbers())
```

It outputs the following list:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61,
 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your logic is correct,* but you have made some indentation errors moreover you have never called `getPrimeNumbers()` in your program. 
I've made few changes and improvements to your code.
Here is the correct code:

```
class PrimeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.givenNumber = number
        self.outputPrimeNumbers = []

    def getPrimeNumbers(self):
        for possiblePrime in range(2, self.givenNumber + 1):
            isPrime = True
            for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
                if possiblePrime % num == 0:
                    isPrime = False

            if isPrime:
                self.outputPrimeNumbers.append(possiblePrime)

    @property
    def getOutputPrimeNumbers(self):
        return self.outputPrimeNumbers


primeClass = PrimeClass(123)
primeClass.getPrimeNumbers() # call the get primes
print(primeClass.getOutputPrimeNumbers) # display the result
```

And the Output will be:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113]
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept the answer as a correct answer and mark the question as completed.